# How to programmatically scroll to a row using react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Is it possible to programmatically scroll to a row using [react-table](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/fixed-header-w-vertical-scroll)[table library for react projects]

ANSWER EDIT:
I ended up adding refs to each rows by formatting Cell. and used this function

```
  scrollToKeyInTable(oldKey, newKey) {
    if (newKey) {
      const node = this._rowRefs.get(newKey);
      try {
        const row = node.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
        const tableBodyNode = row.parentElement;
        tableBodyNode.scrollTop = row.offsetTop - 35;
        const { scrollX, scrollY } = window;
        node.focus({ preventScroll: true });
        window.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);

        return this;
      } catch (e) {}
   } else if (oldKey) {
     const node = this._rowRefs.get(oldKey);
     if (node) {
       node.blur();
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: I have the same request. Any luck with this yet?

Comment: @ArthurHylton I have added answer please check

Comment: That would help if you could put a more comprehensive snippet including the customization you put in table rendering. Thanks

Comment: seriously. Would love to do this, but your code is confusing. What is node?

Comment: @sdb Please add any answers as an answer down below instead of editing the question. It helps keep the site consistent and easy to use. Thanks! 