# How to position a react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a page with a pretty standard react-table. The table has about 30 pages. When you click a row, you get a details page. When you go back, I want to show the table at the position it was at, not at the start. 
Is there something I can do like remembering the position in the table or "start at this particular position" on render?

I don't want to post 200 lines of code here, the source is [here](https://github.com/xtien/schwartze-frontend/blob/develop/src/Letters.js).

Comment: Looks like there are a couple answers out there, including [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583339/how-to-programmatically-scroll-to-a-row-using-react-table) and [this github answer](https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/issues/357).  Have you tried either of these approaches?

Comment: I hadn't seen those, thanks. I'll try.

Comment: I found an easy answere here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50811171/react-table-default-pagination-page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Table default pagination page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50811171/react-table-default-pagination-page)